# Yii2:correct syntax for listbox?

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to use a listbox and using the following syntax for multi-select, which is not working.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'weekday')->listBox([
       'monday'=>'Monday',
        'tuesday'=>'Tuesday',
        'wednesday'=>'Wednesday',
        'thursday'=>'Thursday',
        'friday'=>'Friday',
        'saturday'=>'Saturday',
        'sunday'=>'Sunday'],['multiple'=>true,'size'=>7])

            ?>
```

I am able to multi-select in the list box, but it is returning a null value. If I am taking the part `multiple'=>true` then It is returning the correct value, but then I am not able to multi-select.

What I am doing wrong here?

Thanks.

relevant code in the appointment model.php

public function rules()
    {

```
    return [
        [['appointment_date'], 'safe'],
        [['priority', 'weekday'], 'string', 'max' => 20]
    ];

}
```

controller code:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Appointment();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Stack trace for the error I am getting after update of the suggested code in the answer by aragachev

**Getting unknown property: app\models\Appointment::weekday**
1. in E:\wamp\www\HospitalErp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php at line 143
134135136137138139140141142143144145146147148149150151152

```
 foreach ($this->_behaviors as $behavior) {
            if ($behavior->canGetProperty($name)) {
                return $behavior->$name;
            }
        }
    }
    if (method_exists($this, 'set' . $name)) {
        throw new InvalidCallException('Getting write-only property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
    } else {
        throw new UnknownPropertyException('Getting unknown property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);//line 143
    }
}

/**
 * Sets the value of a component property.
 * This method will check in the following order and act accordingly:
 *
 *  - a property defined by a setter: set the property value
 *  - an event in the format of "on xyz": attach the handler to the event "xyz"

2. in E:\wamp\www\HospitalErp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\BaseActiveRecord.php – yii\base\Component::__get('weekday') at line 247
3. in E:\wamp\www\HospitalErp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\helpers\BaseArrayHelper.php – yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::__get('weekday') at line 190
4. in E:\wamp\www\HospitalErp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\DetailView.php – yii\helpers\BaseArrayHelper::getValue(app\models\Appointment, 'weekday') at line 209
5. in E:\wamp\www\HospitalErp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\DetailView.php – yii\widgets\DetailView::normalizeAttributes() at line 123
6. in E:\wamp\www\HospitalErp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Object.php – yii\widgets\DetailView::init()
```

Comment: Tested it. Everything works fine for me. Is it safe attribute in current scenario? Show the rest of the code related with this attribute (model, controller). Maybe you missed massive assignment?

Comment: Hi arogachev - included the relevant code for model and controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of this is [StringValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-stringvalidator.html) attached to `weekday` attribute in model rules:

```
[['priority', 'weekday'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
```

You are receiving an array, not string (even in case of one selection) because of `multiple => true` option. It simply did not pass validation.

There is no built-in array validator in Yii 2.

**1)** Because you want multiple selection I recommend you to rename `weekday` to `weekdays`.

**2)** I recommend to put weekdays list in separate method:

```
public static function getWeekdaysList()
{
    return [
        'monday' => 'Monday',
        'tuesday' => 'Tuesday',
        'wednesday' => 'Wednesday',
        'thursday' => 'Thursday',
        'friday' => 'Friday',
        'saturday' => 'Saturday',
        'sunday' => 'Sunday',
    ];
}
```

**3)** Create [inline validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-inlinevalidator.html), for example, like this:

```
public function validateWeekdays ($attribute, $params)
{
    $label = '«' . $this->getAttributeLabel($attribute) . '»';

    // Checking if it's array first
    if (is_array(!$this->$attribute)) {    
        $this->addError($attribute, "$label must be array.");

        return;
    }

    $allowedWeekdays = array_keys(static::getWeekdaysList());

    // Checking if every selection is in list of allowed values
    foreach ($this->$attribute as $weekday) 
    {
        if (!in_array($weekday, $allowedWeekdays)) {
            $this->addError($attribute, "$label - $weekday is not in allowed list");

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Read more about inline validators in [offical guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#inline-validators).

**4)** Attach it to `weekdays` in model rules:

```
['weekdays', 'validateWeekDays'],
```

If you don't want to validate `weekDays` you should explicitly mark it as safe attribute in order to massively assign it with other attributes:

```
['weekdays', 'safe'],
```

**5)** In view you can simplify your code to:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'weekdays')->listBox(Appointment::getWeekdaysList(), [
    'multiple' => true,
    'size' => 7,
]) ?>
```

And one little remark - [weekday](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weekday) it's kind of working day, excluding Saturday and Sunday. The more correct form is *days of the week*.

Comment: Hi agrogachev - I have modified the code including renaming the weekday to weekdays - I am now getting the error - `Getting unknown property: app\models\Appointment::weekday`

Comment: You should also change it in the database, for example with help of migration. And check attentively again, maybe you missed renaming somewhere.

Comment: Yes I have changed it in the database, not with the help of migration but in phpmydmin and even overwritten the model.php and then added your code still the same problem.

Comment: Show full stack trace, so we can see the line it's coming from. Or do the global search and replace in your editor, most likely the attribute wilh old name still exists somewhere.

Comment: Hi arogachev - I have added the stack trace for the error - I couldn't find any instances of weekday in the model.

Comment: It's not full, but based on what you provided I guess the error is in view.php file with DetailView widget in it. Check for old attribute 'weekday' and replace it by 'weekdays'. Or if it's hard to find for you, revert the changes of renaming attribute and just check the validation part. Renaming is just an advice and not required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69142/discussion-between-pawan-and-arogachev).